# Istio installation failed

Tags: ibm-cloud, istio

I followed the instructions on https://github.com/IBM/cloud-native-starter/blob/master/documentation/IKSDeployment.md on my Mac, Kubernetes is running on IBM Cloud.

The command

```
$ for i in install/kubernetes/helm/istio-init/files/crd*yaml; do kubectl apply -f $i; done
```

hangs/does not return.

Couldn't validate the istio installation either:

```
$ istioctl verify-install
Error: unknown command "verify-install" for "istioctl"
Run 'istioctl --help' for usage.
```

Comment: If the `kubectl` hangs then for sure this whole installation won't work. You can try pinpointing the issue by running all those `crd*.yaml` files manually and checking which one is problematic. Can I also ask you to do `istioctl version`

Comment: I think it was a temporary glitch, later the command worked as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to solve to problem by following the steps prerequisites for the workshop: https://github.com/IBM/cloud-native-starter/blob/master/workshop/00-prerequisites.md#361-automated-creation-of-a-cluster-with-istio-for-the-workshop

Answer (score 1):

Check out using our managed Istio offering.  To install Istio on your Kubernetes cluster in IBM Cloud run one of the following...

1. Install Istio

   `ic ks cluster-addon-enable istio --cluster xxxx`
2. Install Istio with extra (tracing and monitoring)

   `ic ks cluster-addon-enable istio-extras --cluster xxxx`
3. Install Istio with Bookinfo

   `ic ks cluster-addon-enable istio-sample-bookinfo --cluster xxxx`

In the above xxxx is the name of your cluster.

Comment: I guess the answer is correct, but I only have a free Kubernetes , "istio is not available on free clusters. Create a standard Kubernetes cluster to use the istio managed add-on"; kubectl get pod -n istio-system returns some pods, though

Comment: @jpsstack ah yeah thats correct.  Istio requires a paid cluster because it requires an ingress as well as pv's and pvc's.